# Asp.net 3.1 Selecting Data Error-ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

Tags: asp.net, argumentnullexception

Upgrading from Asp.Net 2.1 to  3.1 I am getting errors on a number of routines that select data with the error ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

The following worked fine in 2.1 but produces this error in 3.1:

```
Lines = _context.DirectoryYearPageLinesInfo.Where(p => p.LName.ToLower() == sLName.ToLower()).Distinct().ToList();
```

This was producing the above error, so I tried Sql:

```
Lines = _context.DirectoryYearPageLinesInfo.FromSqlRaw("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dbo.DirectoryYearPageLinesInfo WHERE LOWER(LName) = '" + sLName + "'").ToList();
```

Same error.
Lines is defined as:

```
IEnumerable<DirectoryYearPageLineInfo> Lines = new List<DirectoryYearPageLineInfo>();
```

DirectoryYearPageLineInfo as:

```
public class DirectoryYearPageLineInfo
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Directory Year")]
    public string DirectoryYear { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Directory Page")]
    public Nullable<int> DirectoryPage { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Directory Line")]
    public Nullable<int> DirectoryLine { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("First Name(s)")]
    public string FName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Last Name(s)")]
    public string LName { get; set; }...
```

The context file:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DirectoryYearPageLineInfo>()
            .HasKey(d => new {d.DirectoryYear, d.DirectoryPage, d.DirectoryLine, d.AddressId });
```

I've tried various things like turning it into a IQueryable, removing Lower, etc., but it always produces the same error.  I feel that there is something I'm missing in the conversion.

Comment: How is the `DirectoryYearPageLinesInfo` property defined on your `DbContext`?

Comment: public DbSet<DirectoryYearPageLineInfo> DirectoryYearPageLinesInfo { get; }

Comment: Does your constructor initialize that property correctly?

Comment: Just realised that there is no set on that one, for some strange reason, must have been removed by accident.  Thanks for asking me for that line, makes all the difference.